# What is a fiber cookie?

Tags: windows, multithreading, fiber

I was browsing through the .NET [Marshall](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class, when I noticed the method GetThreadFromFiberCookie. I tried searching for the term, but only found references to Fibers in the context of threading on Windows. So what is a fiber cookie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getthreadfromfibercookie%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

"Fiber cookies are opaque tokens that are used by the host when alerting the common language runtime to its fiber-scheduling decisions. They consist of a stack and register context."

"A fiber is a particularly lightweight thread of execution...They use co-operative multitasking" - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_%28computer_science%29